# Pasword space is blank under VMWare, what can I do?

Tags: 12.10, password, vmware

I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 on my VMWare and now the password space is just not there. It says the name of user but no space to enter the password. What to do?

Comment: Where? On the login screen? Or the user management?

Comment: Login screen. Is there any option here to add the pics so I can show you exactly.

Comment: Post them to http://wstaw.org and insert them here using the `![](url)` syntax.